# Slot answer returning undefined when wrong answer is given

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

in my quiz, I'm capturing the users answer with

```
handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.answer.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name
```

and comparing it to an answer set in the sessionAttributes. The problem is that when the wrong answer is given, the request object looks like this, with no values to then compare with my session answer:

```
"request": {
                "type": "IntentRequest",
                "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.1e4d598d-2cb8-45fa-80d7-4ea75f544401",
                "timestamp": "2020-05-09T15:12:37Z",
                "locale": "en-US",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "AnswerIntent",
                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                    "slots": {
                        "answer": {
                            "name": "answer",
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

When you give the correct answer, the slot answer is captured correctly and is able to then be compared with the sessionAttribute value:

```
"request": {
                "type": "IntentRequest",
                "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.6da39547-7039-49f4-8138-a9105bb6f010",
                "timestamp": "2020-05-09T15:13:10Z",
                "locale": "en-US",
                "intent": {
                    "name": "AnswerIntent",
                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                    "slots": {
                        "answer": {
                            "name": "answer",
                            "value": "project manager",
                            "resolutions": {
                                "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                                    {
                                        "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.c933b50a-faf5-4f49-8551-838fc1f47fc4.QuizAnswers",
                                        "status": {
                                            "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                                        },
                                        "values": [
                                            {
                                                "value": {
                                                    "name": "Project manager",
                                                    "id": "00f87ea316ec965ecda65285f4e273b6"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                            "source": "USER"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I make it so that I can access the answer no matter if it is correct or incorrect?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you have the slot type Answer defined?

Comment: Here is the code for the user answer and the correct answer. I'm simply comparing the two with an if statement. When the user speaks an incorrect answer, the request object does not have the users's answer recorded anywhere in the object.


`const userAnswer = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.answer.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority[0].values[0].value.name;
        const session = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        const correctAnswer = session.CORRECT_ANSWER;`

Comment: Is this the only place you check for correctness? Do you have any validations in the skill?

Comment: I do not have any validations, though I've seen that option in the dev console. But I'm not very familiar with them. How would I use them? Thank you!

Comment: You would use them if you had like a slot that was more static and had only a small domain. For example if you had a store that only sold socks your slot may be socks and the options black or white.  It sounds like you are going about it the correct way for your use case

Comment: I am curious how Alexa would know it is the wrong answer. If the only place you are validating the answer is in your intent handler you should always get the info. If you are declaring the slot type in the development environment as something where there is an inference of the data type I would add an additional slot to that intent and check the value of both. Use the evaluation model to check slot filling as you go in the developer console.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like:

```
getSpokenWords: function (handlerInput, slot) {
if (handlerInput.requestEnvelope
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots[slot]
    && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots[slot].value)
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots[slot].value;
else return undefined;
}
```

I will edit this later with additional information.